# how to create our own notifications like facebook in our web application

Tags: javascript, .net, web-applications

Basically, am developing a web based project in .NET using C# so I need to create a profile for different set of users and also need to assign them different set of permissions for editing and viewing and retrieving the information from the Database. So, here for each particular Event that is going to happen(i.e precisely writing some data into the Database) I want to give a notification to a particular set of users who can see it when they login. Here, my need is please suggest me how to create a basic profile for users as the number of users are limited to my application and also the core part of this question as in like how do I make notification bar similar to the Face-book(not exactly the replica of it just a simple one which aid me in serving a notification for that particular user profile).

Kindly, free feel and serve me with your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) for this. SignalR is an async library for .NET to create realtime webapplications.

Here you can find an example with a notification system:

[SignalR - Group Notifications](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/404662/SignalR-Group-Notifications)

Comment: You welcome! You can accept and upvote the answers if it helped you.